# What sport was she watching?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

My wife spent her day off yesterday only watching a single sport. She jotted down some scores and left them on the table. I've transcribed them for you here. What sport was she watching?

> Mercedes Williams: 0 - 6
>   Cowboys Indians: 4 - 5
>   Jets Bills: 0 - 3
>   Giants Bengals: 0 - 1
>   Mets Phillies: 4 - 7
>   Lakers Knicks: 1 - 0

---

<sup>My wife wanted to make her own puzzle after seeing some of mine; this is actually her creation.</sup>

Comment: Its seems like NFL

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm taking a pitch it was

> baseball

From these letters

> Mercedes Willi**a**ms: 0 - 6 → a
>  Cow**b**oys Indi**a**ns: 4 - 5 → ba
>  Jets Bi**l**ls: 0 - 3 → l
>  Giants **B**engals: 0 - 1 → b
>  Met**s** Philli**e**s: 4 - 7 → se
>  **L**akers Knicks: 1 - 0 → l
>
>  and abalbsel anagrams to baseball.

Comment: "I'm taking a *pitch*" - I see what you did there.

Comment: Confirmed, this is what she was watching!

Comment: Nice job! this answer is better :P

Comment: I took the same initiative to start solving, but my error was: rot13(hfvat gur 0 nf 0 vaqrk (yvxr cebtenzzvat) fb V qvqa'g trg gur fnzr nantenz lbh tbg!)

Comment: First clue being that most of those numbers are *way* too low to be reasonable scores for their relative sports.  Especially the last one.  Basketball scores tend to run pretty high.  1-0 looks like soccer scores.  (Also the Cowboys and Indians don't even play the same sport...)

Comment: The letters part is not useful - random letters scattered throughout are supposed to be an anagram of the answer? There are enough letters to do the same thing for a number of sports that aren't the answer, such as Conifer's answer.

Comment: @RobWatts What you missed is that the "scores" give you the positions of the chosen letters in the first or second word.  Or no letter is used for a score of 0.  They're not random.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman that would do it. That explanation really should be included in the answer.

Answer (score 6):

I think the sport is:

> Basketball

Reason:

> The score output shows the position of the team name, where to put it on the Number line. Take the space as 0, the left as negative part and the right as positive part:
>
>  Mercedes Williams: $0 - 6 = -6 \to r$
>  Cowboys Indians: $4 - 5 = -1 \to s$
>  Jets Bills: $0 - 3 = -3 \to e$
>  Giants Bengals: $0 - 1 = -1 \to s$
>  Mets Phillies: $4 - 7 = -3 \to e$
>  Lakers Knicks: $1 - 0 = +1 \to K$
>
>  And we got **rseseK**, by proper permutation, we can found a name [**Kresse**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Kresse) who is famous for basketball coach in university for very high win% and a writer.

Comment: Wow! I did not see that coming. I don't think she is a College of Charleston fan though :)

Comment: Tom's answer is more reasonable, and it's MLB postseason right now :D